# how to change the image src in Alpine js like jquery?

Tags: alpine.js

there is a div with  tag that by click on small image I change the src attribute and show it's the original size, but I don't know how to do in Alpine js?

```
<div>
<img id="main" />
</div>

/* small images from db */
<div>
foreach($images as $image){
<img id='small' src="images/.$image" />
}
</div>
```

in jquery :

```
$("#small").each(function(){
$(this).click(function(){
$("#main").attr('src', $(this).attr('src');)
})
})
})
```

**but I don't know how to do in Alpine js?!**

Answer (score 7):

Something like this (using Laravel Blade syntax)?

```html
    <div x-data="{imageUrl: ''}">
      <section>
        <img id="main" :src="imageUrl" />
      </section>

      <hr />

      <div>
        @foreach($images as $image)
            <img id='small' src="{{ images/.$image }}" @click="imageUrl = '{{ images/.$image }}'" />
        @endforeach
      </div>
    </div>
```

Demonstrated in a pen [here](https://codepen.io/kurucu83/pen/qBdzRqY) with some dummy data.

Answer (score 3):

Check this codepen: [Image Preview Demo](https://codepen.io/vmitchell85/pen/yLNzjob). Hope this helps.

```html
<div class="flex items-center justify-center text-gray-500 bg-blue-800 h-screen">
  <div class="w-full">
    <h3 class="mb-8 text-xl text-center text-white">Image Preview Demo</h3>
    <div class="w-full max-w-2xl p-8 mx-auto bg-white rounded-lg">
      <div class="" x-data="imageData()">
        <div x-show="previewUrl == ''">
          <p class="text-center uppercase text-bold">
            <label for="thumbnail" class="cursor-pointer">
              Upload a file
            </label>
            <input type="file" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail" class="hidden" @change="updatePreview()">
          </p>
        </div>
        <div x-show="previewUrl !== ''">
          <img :src="previewUrl" alt="" class="rounded">
          <div class="">
            <button type="button" class="" @click="clearPreview()">change</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-2 text-center text-white">
      <a class="w-32 mx-2" href="https://tailwindcss.com/">TailwindCSS</a>
      <a class="w-32 mx-2" href="https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine">AlpineJS</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I was not what I asked. simply imagine you have a page with to column, left column is the main image and right column many small images and by clicking on them, the main image in the left column updated and show that image in a bigger size.

Comment: See this tutorial on Alpinejs on https://scrimba.com/p/pdqbBcM/cJpnNpUB. I think this is what you are looking for!

Comment: no, it uses many images as hidden and by click make it visible, I need to change to src of the image as jquery do

Answer (score 0):

In AlpineJs you could do something like this.
Not tested, just to make you an idea.

```php
myimages()
{
    return {
        selected: '',
        images: [
            'images/1.png',
            'images/2.png',
            'images/3.png',
            'images/4.png'
        ]
    }
}

<div x-data="myimages()">
    <div>
        <img id="main" :src="selected"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <template x-for="(selimage, index) in images" :key="index">
            <img class='small' :src="selimage" @click="selected = selimage"/>
        </template>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `x-ref` on your main image and then `$ref` in your Alpine data function to set the `src` property of your main image. You could define your main image something like:

```
<img x-ref="mainImage" src="URL TO YOUR FIRST IMAGE" />
```

For each of your thumbnail images, you can do something like:

```
<img src="URL TO THUMBNAIL" x-on:click="pickPhoto(ARRAY INDEX)">
```

Your data function can then include something like this:

```
...
currentPhoto: 0,
photos: [
    "URL TO FIRST IMAGE",
    ...,
    "URL TO LAST IMAGE",
],
pickPhoto(index) {
    this.currentPhoto = index;
    this.$refs.mainImage.src = this.photos[this.currentPhoto];
},
...
```

I have uploaded a working example here:
https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/tailwind-css-with-alpine-js-photo-gallery

Note that this is deliberately designed to allow you to have different URLs from your thumbnails and main images, so the thumbnails can be intrinsically smaller, and load very quickly. If you are using the same images for both, you can simplify the code significantly. Each of your thumbnails could be done like this:

```
<img src="URL TO YOUR FIRST IMAGE" x-on:click="$refs.mainImage.src = 'URL TO YOUR FIRST IMAGE'">
```

With no need for the `pickPhoto` function or the `photos` array.

The downside of the simpler approach is that your page will take longer to load because you won't be using smaller images for your thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

you can for each both of them like this

```html
<div x-data="{image:'0'}">
    <div>
        @foreach ($image_src as $key =>  $image)
            <a href="">
                <img x-show="image==='{{ $key++ }}'"
                     src="{{$image}}" alt="">
            </a>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <div class=" overflow-x-scroll ">
        @foreach ($image_src as $key=> $image)
            <a class="mr-1" on- href="">
                <img :class="{' border border-way-pink':image==='{{ $key }}'}"
                     @click.prevent="image='{{ $key++ }}'"
                     class="w-32 h-24 mr-5" src="{{$image}}" alt="">
            </a>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```